# MVC and conditional formatting - strategies for implementation

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

Right now I am writing a simulation program which output is formatted according to certain factors. The question is in a MVC architecture, where is the conditional formatting to be taken place? What are some strategies for implement this feature?

FYI, The platform I am using is rather bare-bone in its GUI/front-end execution. To change color and formatting, it requires a change to the formatting state (much like OpenGL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is in a MVC architecture,
>   where is the conditional formatting to
>   be taken place?

In the view. It is toally a view element. It may decide to do so based on some additional information in the model.

Example: Exchange TIME AND SALES... I ahve one of those...

The Model has an entry that has a flasgs field indicating whether the sale was at the high, low, at bid or ask etc.

The view uses this flags field to decide on additional coloring.