# Conditional formatting in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Css:

```
.placeHolder {
    color: darkgray
}
```

View:

> Company: @Html.PlaceholderTag(@Model.CompanyName, "Add a
>   company")

Extension Method:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
     public static string PlaceholderTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string placeHolder)
     {
         return string.IsNullOrEmpty(src) ? placeHolder : src;
     }
}
```

The idea is is the companyname is populated it shall be shown in black otherwise it should show the string "Add a company" in dark grey color.

How could I achieve this? The example above outputs always in grey.

**UPDATE**

There are two solutions to this. Creating a ViewModel to wrap the model and add additional flags and View uses a C# conditional on the flags to decide what to do:

Or alternatively using an extension method for an additional HTMLHelper. Effectively MVC does that out of the box with HTml.EditorFor() etc.

```
public static MvcHtmlString PlaceholderTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string placeHolder)
        {
            const string original = "<span>{0}</span>";
            const string formattedPlaceholder = "<span class=\"placeHolder\">{0}</span>";
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(src) ? new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(formattedPlaceholder, placeHolder)) : new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(original, src));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following :

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString PlaceholderTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string placeHolder)
    {
        const string formattedPlaceholder = "<span class=\"placeholder\">{0}</span>";
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(src) ? new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(formattedPlaceholder, src)) : src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. But it wont compile. src is string and cant be converted into MvcHtmlString. I have put an update with the right syntax. Thanks +1.

Answer (score 1):

Add if logic to the view. Set the class or color or whatever you want one way if the companyname is populated and another way if it isn't.

Comment: What happened to separation of concerns?

Comment: I have an idea. I need a ViewModel. I will post the answer soon

Comment: This discussion has a lot of good commentary on how to decide how much logic belongs in your view => http://stackoverflow.com/a/443213/138938   Quoting Phil Haack: Agree, the amount of logic is irrelevant to the separation of concerns. Keeping logic minimal in the views is a practical concern. But view logic belongs in the view. – Haacked Jan 14 '09 at 16:44

Comment: Another useful answer that I just noticed in the "related" column to the right=> http://stackoverflow.com/a/2445803/138938.

Comment: So what did you end up doing?

Comment: Apologies, have been hold off with some family issues. I will update you guys asap. Sofar I tend to HTMLHelpers only if testing would be easy. I will explain why...